# Hibernate OneToOne with a specific clause

Tags: java, hibernate

If somebody knows how-to:

I have an entity

```
@Entity
public class AnEntity {
    ...

    private String propertyA;
    private String propertyB;
    private String propertyC;
}
```

And strings propertyA, propertyB and propertyC are stored in the different table with a refference to AnEntity, name and value fields, something like:

```
@Entity
public class Property {
    ...

    private String name;
    private String value;
}
```

Can I specify OneToOne joins in AnEntity with where clause, I'd like to have something like:

```
@Entity
public class AnEntity {
    ...
    @OneToOne(table = "properties")
    @JoinColumn("anentity_id")
    @WhereJoinTable(name = "propertyA")
    private String propertyA;
    ...
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the easiest way would be to do this:

```
@Entity 
public class AnEntity {
    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn("aentity_id")
    @MapKey(name = "name")
    private Map<String, Property> properties;
    ...
    public getPropertyA() {
        return properties.get("propertyA");
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: The drawback to this approach is that is nests named properties. Say, you want to expose 'billing' address and 'mailing' address directhily on this entity; you can't. They would be exposed this way as: 'properties.billing'

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you create an Entity for the external table and then map propertyA,propertyB and properyyC as delegates to this table?

```
@Entity
public class AnEntity {

    @OneToOne(table = "properties")
    @JoinColumn("anentity_id")
    private Property property;

    public String getPropertyA() {
        return property.getValueA();
    }
}
```

Note: null-checking omitted! :-)